# Fuzzball inside Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, fuzzywuzzy

How to implement Fuzzball Java script as a UDF inside Bigquery? Fuzzball has good amount of dependency libraries which is challenging to include as part of UDF inside Bigquery.

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/tree/master/udfs This will get you Fuzzball and a large library of other highly useful UDFs

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear where you're running into trouble, so I will walk through the process of creating a JavaScript UDF using fuzzball.

1. Download the fuzzball package: `npm i fuzzball`
2. Upload the appropriate file(s) to a GCS bucket.  What you want is likely a umd or esm file.  At time of writing, `fuzzball.umd.min.js`
3. Write your SQL UDF, providing the bucket path and package file in `OPTIONS`.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  project.table.func (str_1 STRING, str_2 STRING)
RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js AS '''
return fuzzball.distance(str_1, str_2);
'''
OPTIONS (library='gs://bucket_name/fuzzball.umd.min.js');
```

And now you should be able to call your UDF as needed.